# Sorting a list of positions based on values stored in 2 other lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to generate a position list (from 0 to n) for points (streetlights) based on their distance to other points (street).

The lists look like this :

```
lightpoint_list =  [14, 20, 1, 1, 12, 6] 
distance_list = [3.79, 7.91, 9.27, 22.14, 13.91, 1.27]
order_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The order in which they appear is important since I have to add this data in a Dataframe and respect its original order. For example :

```
FID     X       Y      lightpoint_list    distance_list    order
 1    45.33    69.32         14                3.79
 2    45.32    69.22         20                7.91
 3    45.31    69.20         1                 9.27
 4    45.28    69.19         1                 22.14
 5    45.20    69.21         12                13.91
 6    45.22    69.31         6                 1.27
```

In this scenario, FID 1 does not necessarely mean that this point is the first on the street, only that it has been entered first. I need to order these points by their 
order of appearance on the street. To do so, I matched each lightpoint to its closest point on the street by segmenting the line into points. These results are stored in
lightpoint_list where each value is the index value of the corresponding segmentend point on the street. We want to generate an order starting from 0 and going to n (in
this particular example, 5) based on their order of appearance on the street (i.e lightpoint_list value).

From this, we understand that lightpoint_list value 1 appears before 6, and so on. The distance_list is generated in case 2 lightpoint_list have the same value. If that
happens, it means that 2 streetlights are closest to the point 1 (in this case) than any other points on the street. In order to know which point comes first in order
of appearance, the distance between the streetlight and the segmented point of the street is computed and stored in distance list.

We understand then that if there is no duplicates in lightpoint_list, we do not need the distance_list and can simply rank the points by ascending order. However, if we have 
duplicates (like in this case), we need to refer to the distance of these duplicates and sort them by ascending distance.

A result of this would be :

```
 order_list = [4, 5, 0, 1, 3, 2]
```

that I could append to a Dataframe like this :

```
FID     X       Y      lightpoint_list    distance_list    order
 1    45.33    69.32         14                3.79          4
 2    45.32    69.22         20                7.91          5
 3    45.31    69.20         1                 9.27          0
 4    45.28    69.19         1                 22.14         1
 5    45.20    69.21         12                13.91         3
 6    45.22    69.31         6                 1.27          2
```

Comment: Can you please name all these list and specify the input and desired output more clearly

Comment: And the list which has the minimum distance between light point and street point how it can have 5 elements? Distance between 5 point will have 4 values? Isn’t it?

Comment: Here you go Raman, I update the question. I hope it is simpler to understand. If anything isn't clear, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do. It might help illustrate if you show the code you've written to try to solve this yourself.

Comment: I don't understand how you are calculating that output. Can you walk through how to generate some of the elements by hand? Why is `4` the first element? Why is `2` the last element?

Comment: Sure ! Basically, I designed a function to segment a line into points, and order the streetlights along that line (now segmentend in points). It is fairly hard to explain, but basically, the line is segmented in points (indexed from 0 to n). Then, each streetlight is compared to every segmented point and the one closest to the streetlight will yield it its index. For instance, the first number in the list is 4, meaning this streetlight was closest from the segmented point #4 on the street.

Comment: Try to show why `4` is the first element using what you have above (i.e. show why `4` is first by using values from `lightpoint_list` and `distance_list`).

Your current explanation isn't very helpful. It sounds like you're saying it's `4` because segment #4 is first in the list...which is a circular explanation. We understand that you _want_ it to be first, but you'll have to explain _why_ it is first if you want a proper generalization

Comment: I edited the question, hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to sorted first by `lightpoint_list`, if lightpoint is same, then sorted by `distance_list`. so the solution is clear, you can just pack and sort:

```
lightpoint_list = [14, 20, 1, 1, 12, 6]
distance_list = [3.79, 7.91, 9.27, 22.14, 13.91, 1.27]
order_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

sorted_data = sorted(zip(lightpoint_list, distance_list, order_list))

print(f"sorted_data={sorted_data}")

for i, data in enumerate(sorted_data):
    order_list[data[2]] = i

print(f"order_list={order_list}")
```

output:

```
sorted_data=[(1, 9.27, 2), (1, 22.14, 3), (6, 1.27, 5), (12, 13.91, 4), (14, 3.79, 0), (20, 7.91, 1)]
order_list=[4, 5, 0, 1, 3, 2]
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much, I won't forget that one hehe :)